# C++ 2D Array loops over to first cell in row when calling nearby cell

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm writing a Minesweeper program in C++, and at the moment I'm trying to assign each cell on the 2D grid a value for the mines within the 8-cell "donut" around it. I'm using a 2D string array to hold the values of each cell. An "X" denotes a mine.

I have "safetys" in place to prevent the array from trying to find the value of nonexistent cells, but the cells on the right-hand side still loop over to detect bombs on the far left-hand side.

Here's a little of the code that detects the bombs in the local area:

```cpp
//main
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int numNearbyBombs = 0;
while (i < (ySize)) //Nearby Bomb Detection
    {
        while (j < (xSize))
        {
            if ((hiddenBoard[i][j] != "X"))
            {
                if (j != xSize) //Safety
                {
                    if (hiddenBoard[i][j + 1] == "X") //Checks to the right
                    {
                        ++numNearbyBombs;
                    }
                }
            //Check other directions
            //Replace hiddenBoard[i][j] with numNearbyBombs
            numNearbyBombs = 0;
            }
            ++j;
        }
        ++i;
        j = 0;
    }
```

I've already tried modifying the "safety" (if) statement to trip if `(j == (xSize - 1))`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Some sample output:

```
  1  2  3
A X  4  X
B X  X  5
C X  4  X
```

The output looks fine, except the "5" at B3 should be a "3". The code for some reason detects the "X"s at B1 and C1, but strangely NOT at A1.

To clarify, I want B3 to only find A3, B2, and C3 as bombs. However, the code finds B1 and C1 as bombs as well.

Comment: You have a check `if (j != xSize)` inside `while (j < (xSize))` loop body. Explain to your nearest rubber duck what this check does. When exactly the condition becomes false? Give an example with specific numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you have loop condition `j < (xSize)` and then safety condition `j != xSize`, which is useless, because the loop condition already guarantees that the second condition is true.

Moreover, neither of those conditions prevent `j + 1` to become xSize. However, the acceptable range of values is from 0 to xSize - 1. So you are checking for bombs outside of acceptable boundaries and that is why you are getting incorrect result.

Here is your code rewritten to check all eight directions correctly:

```
// Nearby Bomb Detection
for (int i = 0; i < ySize; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < xSize; j++) {
        if (hiddenBoard[i][j] != "X") {
            int numNearbyBombs = 0;

            if (j + 1 < xSize && hiddenBoard[i][j + 1] == "X")          // Checks to the right
                ++numNearbyBombs;

            if (j - 1 >= 0 && hiddenBoard[i][j - 1] == "X")             // Checks to the left
                ++numNearbyBombs;

            if (i - 1 >= 0) {
                if (hiddenBoard[i - 1][j] == "X")                       // Checks strictly to the top
                    ++numNearbyBombs;
                if (j + 1 < xSize && hiddenBoard[i - 1][j + 1] == "X")  // Checks top right
                    ++numNearbyBombs;
                if (j - 1 >= 0 && hiddenBoard[i - 1][j - 1] == "X")     // Checks top left
                    ++numNearbyBombs;
            }

            if (i + 1 < ySize) {
                if (hiddenBoard[i + 1][j] == "X")                       // Checks strictly to the bottom
                    ++numNearbyBombs;
                if (j + 1 < xSize && hiddenBoard[i + 1][j + 1] == "X")  // Checks bottom right
                    ++numNearbyBombs;
                if (j - 1 >= 0 && hiddenBoard[i + 1][j - 1] == "X")     // Checks bottom left
                    ++numNearbyBombs;
            }

            //Replace hiddenBoard[i][j] with numNearbyBombs
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.